# What is the nuance between “yet” and “ever” in these sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

Here are the sentences:

> Her latest novel is her best yet.
>
> It’s one of the toughest warnings yet delivered.

Replacing *yet* with *ever*, how does it feel different?

Answer (score 4):

> Her latest novel is her best yet.
>
> Her latest novel is her best ever.

I think the meaning is the same there because of the modifier **her latest** (that is, **ever** and **yet** would both be understood to mean "so far"); but **ever** is in a more informal register and a bit gushy whereas **yet** is neutral.

> It’s one of the toughest warnings yet delivered.

So far, *in the current context or situation*, this has been among the toughest warnings.

> It’s one of the toughest warnings ever delivered.

Absent further context, it is one of the toughest warnings delivered in any situation at any time.

Answer (score 0):

"Yet" means up to now while "ever", well, means ever (which can also refer to the future). So the sentence

> "Her latest novel is her best yet."

means that the writer is still alive and might write a better novel but up to now it is the best novel she has written. But if we say

> "Shakspear's best play yet is Hamlet."(***WRONG***)

it would be meaningless since he is dead and is not able to write any more plays. So we would have to say "Shakspear's best play ever was Hamlet."